# How to create a method that returns the API response

Tags: c#, .net, api, http, restsharp

I'm using restsharp as HTTP client, and i don't know how to make possible that API response to return as specific model, or it can be returned as a string or something like that,  I know that i'm using async/await, but how can do it correctly for my requirement

```
  //my api model
     class ApiModel
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }


      // api call
       public static async Task ApiCall()
        {
            
            var client = new RestClient("https://google.com/");
            var request = new RestRequest("api/get_something", Method.Get);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
            // i want to return like this 
            var customRes = new ApiModel();
            customRes.Content = response.Content;
            return customRes;

        }
```

Comment: `Task<ApiModel>`?

Comment: yes i try it but does not return as my model, its return all object as System.Threading.Task

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static async Task<ApiModel> ApiCall(){

var client = new RestClient("https://google.com/");
var request = new RestRequest("api/get_something", Method.Get);
var result = client.Execute<ApiModel>(request).Data;
return result ;
}
```

Comment: 'string' does not contain a defination for 'ReadAsStringAsync' and no accessible extention methot 'ReadAsStringAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found @amjad

Comment: @Amjad `RestClient` != `HttpClient`

Comment: i edit the asnwer. can you check it if it works for you?

Comment: @AmjadSaab no, doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

you have to deserialize response

```
public static async Task<ActionResult<ApiModel>> ApiCall()
{
 .... your code
  var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json =  response.Content;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiModel>(json);
        return  Ok(result)

         //or you have to post API model, I can only guess
       
        return Ok( new ApiModel { Content= ... I dont know what});

    }    
          
   return BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: its give me error like  'string' does not contain a defination for 'ReadAsStringAsync' and no accessible extention methot 'ReadAsStringAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: @AGK  I fixed my answer. Pls post your API model. I don't know what type is content there. And why you don't use http clienst as it is recomended?

Comment: I don't think OP is hosting a web API, so the Ok() calls may need to be replaced with simple returns.

Comment: @JohnGlenn Thanks for a feedback. I added it since OP doesn't  have any error validation and doesn't return any errors messages